# Adding comments section to Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, image-gallery

I am creating a jquery image gallery and I am using fancy box to generate modal image overlay when thumbnails are clicked. Could you suggest how to add comments section to the fancy box overlay along with the zoomed image(Just like how Facebook has comments section to the right hand corner of the modal overlay)? Does fancy box have a functionality for this?  If not, could you suggest how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fancybox doesn't offer that functionality out-of-the-box but you could customize your own solution.

You could also consider my fancybox "a la" Facebook :

http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxALAfacebook_26Mar12.html

It requires fancybox v2.x