# Jquery Lightbox Like Facebook and Google + Photo Viewer

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox, lightbox

I have no really found any good solutions yet

I have a Rails 3 website that has an image gallery.
Each Image Has comments

I want to load the Image, and the comments into FancyBox or Lightbox
and Display comments just like Facebook, and Google +

What is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/11184264/1055987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just played a little with [lightboxme](http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/) and came up with this simple example on how to make it. Notice you have to implement all the styling and the flow for changing from one image to another.

http://jsfiddle.net/eKuhH/1/

Comment: Im still new to JS, im pretty well versed in rails, html, and css... my only lack is the that really awesome JS... that i should know but dont ..... Do you have any more resources where i can review some JS and learn to put together something like this?